# Parametized getter in Vuex - trigger udpate

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

My Vuex store has a collection of data, say 1,000 records. There is a getter with a parameter, getItem, taking an ID and returning the correct record.

I need components accessing that getter to know when the data is ready (when the asynchronous fetching of all the records is done).

However since it's a parametized getter, Vue isn't watching the state it depends on to know when to update it. What should I do?

I keep wanting to revert to a BehaviorSubject pattern I used in Angular a lot, but Vuex + rxJS seems heavy for this, right?

I feel I need to somehow emit a trigger for the getter to recalculate.

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    numberOfPosts : -1,
    posts : {}, //dictionary keyed on slug
    postsLoaded : false,
  },
  getters : {
    postsLoaded : function(state){
      return state.postsLoaded;
    },
    totalPosts : function(state){
      return state.numberOfPosts;
    },
    post: function( state ){
      return function(slug){
        if( state.posts.hasOwnProperty( slug ) ){
          return state.posts.slug;
        }else{
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    storePosts : function(state, payload){
      state.numberOfPosts = payload.length;
      for( var post of payload ){
        state.posts[ post.slug ] = post;
      }
      state.postsLoaded = true;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchPosts(context) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        Vue.http.get(' {url redacted} ').then((response) => {
          context.commit('storePosts', response.body);
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Post.vue

```
 <template>
      <div class="post">
        <h1>This is a post page for {{ $route.params.slug }}</h1>
        <div v-if="!postsLoaded">LOADING</div>
        <div v-if="postNotFound">No matching post was found.</div>
        <div v-if="postsLoaded && !postNotFound" class="post-area">
          {{ this.postData.title.rendered }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'post',
  data : function(){
    return {
      loading : true,
      postNotFound : false,
      postData : null
    }
  },
  mounted : function(){
    this.postData = this.post( this.$route.params.slug );
    if ( this.postData == null ){
      this.postNotFound = true;
    }
  },
  computed : mapGetters([
    'postsLoaded',
    'post'
  ])
}
</script>
```

As it stands, it shows the "post not found" message because when it accesses  the getter, the data isn't ready yet. If a post isn't found, I need to distinguish between (a) the data is loaded and there isn't a post that matches, and (b) the data isn't loaded so wait

Comment: Would be extremely helpful if you could post some of your code.

Comment: Thought it was more conceptual, but fair point, I've added the store code and a component, with some unrelated code stripped out.

Comment: All good, if I didn't say something someone else would. Stack overflow is aimed at specific code questions and answers (even though it doesn't always end up that way.) Software Engineering on Stack Exchange is more well suited for conceptual problems. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
But thanks for adding for a code example! (pseudo-code is also acceptiable in these scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem lies with how your are setting the posts array in your storePosts mutation, specifially this line:

```
state.posts[ post.slug ] = post
```

VueJs can't track that operation so has no way of knowing that the array has updated, thus your getter is not updated.

Instead your need to use Vue set like this:

```
Vue.set(state.posts, post.slug, post)
```

For more info see [Change Detection Caveats documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't use code to illustrate my idea as there isn't a running code snippet for now. I think what you need to do is that:

1. Access the vuex store using `mapGetters` in computed property, which you already did in `Post.vue`.
2. [Watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) the mapped getters property inside your component, in your case there would be a watcher function about `postsLanded` or `post`, whatever you care about its value changes. You may need `deep` or `immediate` property as well, check [API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch).
3. Trigger mutations to the vuex store through actions, and thus would change the store's value which your getters will get.
4. After the watched property value changes, the corresponding watch function would be fired with old and new value and you can complete your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

code sample of mark's answer

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'customerData',
        ])
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['customerGetRecords']),
},
created() {
    this.customerGetRecords({
        url: this.currentData
    });
```

Comment: It will be good if you can provide a small writeup for the solution